# Answers to Reviewers

Tags: paper-submission, peer-review

We submitted a manuscript, received the reviews, and answered them all. We answered all of their comments, every single one, but my simple question is that if we are obliged to mention every minor change we do in the manuscript or not.

Comment: I do not mention any changes not requested by reviewers.  Say during revision, I find an error.  I will not mention the correction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you say "answered" I assume you mean addressed the comments in the manuscript itself. But, no, you needn't list all changes, especially minor ones. Let the new version stand for itself.

There is a tradeoff in listing minor changes. While it might help that same reviewer do a quick scan of the new version, it also makes it less likely they will treat the new version as an organic whole.

List any major changes and point to changes caused by special concerns of reviewers, of course.

Comment: Thank you so much @Buffy for continuous help and support...

Comment: Do we add highlights (i.e yellow color) in the manuscript to the changes that are related to our answers?

Comment: Please not yellow.  https://discoveryeye.org/print-and-web-design-for-older-adults/

Comment: No, don't use highlighting. Let the paper be the paper. Ad thanks to @TerryLoring for the note on considering older readers, which should be a general concern.